# How to enable a bool by holding left click and disable that bool

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I am quite new to Unity.

```
private bool scoreIncreasing;

void Update() 
{ 
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    { 
        scoreIncreasing = true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        scoreIncreasing = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, especially 'disable that bool if I am not' ...

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 events for key or button:

1. `GetMouseButtonDown` invokes only once when it was pressed
2. `GetMouseButtonUp` invokes only once when it was released
3. `GetMouseButton` every frame while button is holded

For your case change `GetMouseButtonDown` to `GetMouseButton`

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a great day!